# How to map object to table react typescript

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, object, mapping

I'm trying to make a table from array of objects which have items, arrays and objects.

But mapping in typescript is so challenging for me.

I tried it this way, but I get no data rendered, just empty cells(by the way, all names of columns are already written)

```
<tr>
            {items?.map((item, key: any) => {
              return (
                <>
                  {Object.keys(item).map((pole) => {
                    return (
                      <>
                        <td>{(item as any)[pole].request_date}</td>
                        <td>{(item as any)[pole].invoice_number}</td>
                      </>
                    );
                    // return console.log((item as any)[pole]);
                  })}
                </>
              );
            })}
</tr>
```

etc.

Here you can see data from server, it's not full, but shows the main aim of task. Is it even real like I want

```
[
        {
            "_id": "63746fb7d938e62729d7727d",
            "request_date": "2022-12-08T23:00:00.000Z",
            "invoice_number": "invoice2",
            "container": {
                "container_number": "1",
                "container_type": "H20",
                "_id": "63746fb7d938e62729d7726d",
            },
            "importers": [
                {
                    "name": "importer1",
                    "container": "63746fb7d938e62729d7726d",
                    "_id": "63746fb7d938e62729d77275",
                },
                {
                    "name": "importer2",
                    "container": "63746fb7d938e62729d7726d",
                    "_id": "63746fb7d938e62729d77276",
                },
                {
                    "name": "importer3",
                    "container": "63746fb7d938e62729d7726d",
                    "_id": "63746fb7d938e62729d77277",
                }
            ]
        },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution, it's a lot more easier than I thought.

First of all you need to make interface for object which you will `map()`.
Than it's classic map into table cells.

```
interface Container = {
  container_number: string;
  container_type: string;
  _id: string;
};

interface Importers = {
  name: string;
  _id: string;
};

interface Providers {
  name: string;
  _id: string;
};

interface TableProps {
  data: {
    _id: string;
    request_date: string;
    invoice_number: string;
    container: Container;
    importers: Importers[];
    providers: Providers[];
  }[];
}
```

Also if you have arrays or objects in your main object, you need to make interfaces for them all, as I show it.

and just iterate through array of objects

```
<tbody>
            {data.map((item, key) => {
              return (
                <tr key={item._id}>
                  <td>{item.request_date}</td>
                  <td>{item.invoice_number}</td>
                  <td>{item.container.container_number}</td>
                  <td>
                    <table className="table-importers">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          {item.importers.map((importer) => {
                            return <td key={importer._id}>{importer.name}</td>;
                          })}
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <table className="table-importers">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          {item.providers.map((provider) => {
                            return <td key={provider._id}>{provider.name}</td>;
                          })}
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
</tbody>
```

I'm not sure if it's a best practice, but it works 100%

Thank you !